# What is the correct syntax to DT updateSearch() keywords argument?

Tags: r, json, shiny, datatables, dt

My Shiny app has an alternate input to filter a datatable, and I would like it to update a specific column filter in the datatable. I am using `updateSearch()` to do so.

Here is the keyword argument help page reproduced:

```
keywords    
a list of two components: global is the global search keyword of a single character string (ignored if NULL); columns is a character vector of the search keywords for all columns (when the table has one column for the row names, this vector of keywords should contain one keyword for the row names as well)
```

Followed by a reprex where I am trying to use a button to update the search filter for species (the 5th and last column of the datatable) to `setosa`. The filter supplied to columns is the character vector `c("", "", "", "", "setosa")`.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton(
        inputId = "filter",
        label = "Add Filter"
    ),
    DTOutput("dt")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$dt <- renderDT({
        iris %>%
            datatable(
                filter = "top",
                rownames = FALSE
            )
    })
    
    proxy <- dataTableProxy("dt")
    
    blank <- ""
    
    observeEvent(input$filter, {
        proxy %>% updateSearch(
            keywords = list(
                columns = c(
                    rep(blank, 4),
                    "setosa"
                )
            )
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I get the following warning as a popup (not in console):

```
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       setosa 
                     (right here) ------^
```

Needless to say I have tried several possible formats for the `columns` parameter and they all don't work. I've tried:

```
columns = "setosa"
```

Which fills every column filter with `setosa` but generates this error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Error in filterRange(x, search_string): The range of a numeric / date / time column must be of length 2
```

This seems to suggest that `blank` as `""` is not a valid empty filter for numeric columns, so I tried:

```
blank <- "0 ... 1"
```

Which filters to an empty table (even though all the numeric columns do have values in that range.

Existing examples of `updateSearch()` online are almost exclusively about using an existing table filter inputted manually, and supplying that input to `updateSearch()`'s `columns` parameter. So I tried filtering the table by hand and copying the `input$dt_search_columns` by querying it with a `browser()`:

```
Called from: observe()
Browse[1]> input$dt_search_columns
[1] ""             ""             ""             ""            
[5] "[\"setosa\"]"
Browse[1]> input$dt_search_columns %>% class()
[1] "character"
```

So I tried the following:

```
columns = c("", "", "", "", "[\"setosa\"]")
```

Which worked! So it requires it to be in brackets. Interestingly, the following does not work:

```
columns = c("", "", "", "", "['setosa']")
```

Resulting in:

```
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                      ['setosa'] 
                     (right here) ------^
```

However this works, which I believe has to do with `json` not accepting single quotes:

```
columns = c("", "", "", "", '["setosa"]')
```

Rather than use trial and error, could someone point me to clear documentation about how this `columns` parameter should be formatted? Things get even more complicated with numeric filters.

Comment: I never used that, but my guess is that you have to give an array, hence the brackets. For exampe `["setosa","virginica"]`.